# finally working in java before stackoverflow with a recursive loop in main()

Tags: java, recursion, try-catch, control-flow

```
class exception1 {
    public static void main(String s[]) {
        String v[] = new String[2];
        try {
            main(v);
            System.out.println(5 / 0);

        }
        catch (Exception e) // or (ArithmeticException e)
        {
            System.out.println(e); // Java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero

        }
        finally {
            System.out.println("AAAA");
        }
        System.out.println("after finally normal execution");
    }
}
```

When i run this code, i get countless AAAA's till the stackoverflow error occurs. My question is main(v); calls the main again and yet finally runs :( ? Control flow is somewhat out of my conscience. Is finally so arrogant that it does not even care about main?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, note that `StackOverflowError` is an `Error` and not an `Exception`, so it won't be caught in your `catch (Exception e)`.

When the `StackOverflowError` is thrown, that exception will propagate up in the call stack. Each time a stack-frame returns exceptionally, it's finally clause will be executed.

(The `0/5` expression is not reachable, as you've probably discovered.)

Here's a picture of what happens:

```
                                                               Output
main()
   main()
       main()
          ...
             main()

                 throw Stack-overflow!
                 Print AAAA before returning exceptionally     AAAA

             rethrow Stack-overflow!
             Print AAAA before returning exceptionally         AAAA

         ...                                                   ...

      rethrow Stack-overflow!
      Print AAAA before returning exceptionally                AAAA

   rethrow Stack-overflow!
   Print AAAA before returning exceptionally                   AAAA

Uncaught stack-overflow error, print stacktrace.               Exception dump.
```

Comment: Which is good to know. I know that they are supposed to, but nice to see it work here (even in the presence of a somewhat critical error).

Comment: but AAAA's are printed then comes stackoverflow and den execution stops.. AS is saw it while executing

Comment: Ah, let me clarify my answer... give me a sec.

Comment: No. First the Stackoverflow *happens*, then everything prints as the stack gets unwound, and then the Stackoverflow exception is *printed* (by the default exception handler that runs just before the JVM exits).

Comment: If you put a breakpoint at StackOverflowError, you can see that in a debugger.

Comment: Right, the confusion is due to the fact that the stack traces is not printed when it is first thrown, but when it has propagated out to the JVM (is uncaught).

Comment: what i got from your answer is ... main main main main and so on... stackoverflow occurs and exception caught and finally prints AAAA.. am i right? if so, after finally prog. should end ?

Comment: The stack-overflow exception is never caught. It's more like main main main, throw, finally finally finally, uncaught-exception-gets-dumped.

Comment: the catch block won't catch it ?

Comment: No, `StackOverflowError` is an `Error` and not an `Exception`. If you change to `catch (Throwable e)` you'll get a different output. Answer updated.

Comment: @aioobe : I debugged program, at last finally block output `AAAA` is printed on console

Comment: how stupid of me reading the error as exception :(. thanks for clearing. buti am confused :( main main main stackoverflow error then as you said "Print AAAA before returning exceptionally ". Print AAAA is ok but i don't understand returning exceptionlly

Comment: If a method throws an exception (either explicitly, or by calling a method that throws it) which it does not catch, it returns exceptionally. (When a method doesn't return by a return-statement)

Comment: So in this case main is throwing an exception which is not getting caught then finally is printed and the control returns to main(v); exceptionally that rethrows same error and again AAAA is printed ? KILL ME IF I AM NOT RIGHT :X

Comment: That's exactly what happens :)

Answer (score 2):

Another answer with a programmatic explanation..

```
class TryFinallyDemo
{
    static int counter;

    public static void main(String s[])
    {
        int localCounter=0;
        String v[] = new String[2]; 

        try{ 
            counter++;
            localCounter = counter;
            main(v); 
            System.out.println(5/0);                                     
        } 


        catch(Exception e)  // or (ArithmeticException e) 
        {   
            System.out.println(e); // Java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero 
        }                                      

        finally{ System.out.println("AAAA.. Local Counter is " + localCounter);  }      

        System.out.println("after finally normal execution");  

    } 
}
```

This example clearly shows how the stack is called back from bottom to top once the StackOverflow error is thrown.

Snippet of Output:

```
AAAA.. Local Counter is 47
AAAA.. Local Counter is 46
AAAA.. Local Counter is 45
AAAA.. Local Counter is 44
AAAA.. Local Counter is 43
AAAA.. Local Counter is 42
AAAA.. Local Counter is 41
AAAA.. Local Counter is 40
AAAA.. Local Counter is 39
AAAA.. Local Counter is 38
AAAA.. Local Counter is 37
AAAA.. Local Counter is 36
AAAA.. Local Counter is 35
AAAA.. Local Counter is 34
AAAA.. Local Counter is 33
AAAA.. Local Counter is 32
AAAA.. Local Counter is 31
AAAA.. Local Counter is 30
AAAA.. Local Counter is 29
AAAA.. Local Counter is 28
AAAA.. Local Counter is 27
AAAA.. Local Counter is 26
AAAA.. Local Counter is 25
AAAA.. Local Counter is 24
AAAA.. Local Counter is 23
AAAA.. Local Counter is 22
AAAA.. Local Counter is 21
AAAA.. Local Counter is 20
AAAA.. Local Counter is 19
AAAA.. Local Counter is 18
AAAA.. Local Counter is 17
AAAA.. Local Counter is 16
AAAA.. Local Counter is 15
AAAA.. Local Counter is 14
AAAA.. Local Counter is 13
AAAA.. Local Counter is 12
AAAA.. Local Counter is 11
AAAA.. Local Counter is 10
AAAA.. Local Counter is 9
AAAA.. Local Counter is 8
AAAA.. Local Counter is 7
AAAA.. Local Counter is 6
AAAA.. Local Counter is 5
AAAA.. Local Counter is 4
AAAA.. Local Counter is 3
AAAA.. Local Counter is 2
AAAA.. Local Counter is 1
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at java.lang.String.indexOf(String.java:1395)
```

Answer (score 2):

I debugged program, This was flow :

> main()-> main()-> main-> ........got stackoverflow exception -> finally -> finally -> finally ->..... control with stackoverflow exception transferred to main thread from main() method and main thread handled stackoverflow exception

**Output**

```
AAAA
AAAA
AAAA
AAAA
....
AAAA
AAAA
AAAA
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractOwnableSynchronizer.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock$Sync.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock$NonfairSync.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap$Segment.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.ensureSegment(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.putIfAbsent(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.getClassLoadingLock(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at test.exception1.main(Exception1.java:17)
    at test.exception1.main(Exception1.java:7)
    at test.exception1.main(Exception1.java:7)
    ....
    at test.exception1.main(Exception1.java:7)
    at test.exception1.main(Exception1.java:7)
    at test.exception1.main(Exception1.java:7)
```

Comment: main()-> main()-> main-> ........got stackoverflow error ok prints finally(aaaa0) ok. But how come the control goes back again ? so that there is a stackerror again and prints aaaa1

Comment: ohh. i was talking with the reference from above answer !

Answer (score 1):

`main(v)` is called before reaches `5/0` operation so exception isn't thrown - there occures infinite loop.

Comment: so control goes to main(v), then finally occurs and den main is called ?

Comment: He's never claiming that any arithmetic exception is thrown. He's saying that StackOverflowException is thrown, and *it is*.

Comment: @rd4code The best way is to set some breakpoint in `catch` statement. You will see if it goes there.

Comment: I know that it will not go to catch.. just at the time of execution i see that AAAA's are getting printed den comes stackoverflow !.. control goes to main(v); then finally and then main(String s[]) is called ?